# Spring data joins for specification

Tags: spring, specifications

I have following entities:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
class Emplyee {

  @Id
  long id

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "EMPLOYEE_TASK", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID"),
  inverseJoinColumns(@JoinColumn(name = "TASK_ID"))
  Set<Task> tasks
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Task")
class Task {

  @Id
  long id

 //any relation to Employee
}
```

I would like to have an spring `Specification` which allows me to get those employees who have at least one common task with given id list:

```java
List<Employee> employeesByTaskId(Set<Long> taskIds)
```

How should `Specification` interface be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

Now you can write a specification like this:

```java
public Specification<Emplyee> hasTaskIdIn(Set<Long> taskIds) {
    return (Specification<Emplyee>)
            (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) ->
                    criteriaBuilder
                            .in(root.join("tasks").get("id"))
                            .value(taskIds);
}
```

**How will we execute these specifications?** To do so, you simply extend `JpaSpecificationExecutor`, in your repository interface and thus “pull in” an API to execute `Specifications`:

```java
public interface EmployeeRepository extends 
        JpaRepository<Employee, Long>, 
        JpaSpecificationExecutor<Employee> {}
```

You can now do:

```java
...
employeeRepository.findAll(hasTaskIdIn(
        new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1l, 2l)));
...
```

You can read this post for more information. https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/